# Handling json.loads() Value Error in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, ujson

when I try to run this code I am experiencing an error.

```
import ujson as json

input = '{"a":NaN}'
print(json.loads(input))
```

**Error**

```
print(json.loads(input))
ValueError: Expected object or value
```

I gone through some blogs and realized that ujson won't handle `nan` or `NaN` values while performing `json.loads` operation.

**My final goal:**
I want to

1. use ujson to load the string into JSON-FORMAT
2. handle this type of VALUE ERRORS
3. load the input string into  JSON

**Note:my input might be nested json structure**

```
input = {"name":"siva","details":{"id":"111","qualification":nan},"marks":[{"grade1":90,"grade2":null,"grade3":NaN}]}
```

**Expected output**

```
{"a":NaN}
{"name":"siva","details":{"id":"111","qualification":nan},"marks":[{"grade1":90,"grade2":null,"grade3":NaN}]}
```

**Can anyone suggest a solution for this?**

Comment: Why not using `json` instead of `ujson`? it works with you example

Comment: You can’t handle value errors during parsing of json. It is either entirely correct or there is an error. If you want to detect invalid values you have to do that yourself. Did you mean: ‘input = '{"a":null}’. ?

Comment: @SpiderPig1297, `ujson` is faster than `json`, thats why i want to use `ujson`

Comment: by the way, don't use `input` as variable name

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the expected output that you seek (it will be great if you could also add it).

The following code will perform without any errors:

```
import json
import re

in1 = '{"Number": nan}'
in1 = re.sub(r'\bnan\b', 'NaN', in1)
print(json.loads(in1))
# {'Number': nan}
in2 = '{"name":"siva","details":{"id":"111","qualification":nan},"marks":[{"grade1":90,"grade2":null,"grade3":NaN}]}'
in2 = re.sub(r'\bnan\b', 'NaN', in2)
print(json.loads(in2))
# {'name': 'siva', 'details': {'id': '111', 'qualification': nan}, 'marks': [{'grade1': 90, 'grade2': None, 'grade3': nan}]}
```

Comment: i just want to extract the JSON- STRING as it is. for your reference, i added sample output. please check it.

Comment: @siva you can't get the desired output, but with `json` you will able to get as close to it, but you still need to use `re.sub` to change the `nan` because it recognize only `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

`NaN` is not a valid JSON symbol, see the spec at http://json.org/
`ujson` does not support load of `nan`/`inf`. See https://github.com/ultrajson/ultrajson/issues/146 for more info

In my opinion attempt to replace `nan` with `null` is prone to errors.
use `json` from Standard Library. Here is link to [relevant part of the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#infinite-and-nan-number-values)

Comment: Is Standard `json` library handle `nan` or `NaN` values?

Comment: yes - check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Answer (score 0):

The best options is to use jsonpickle to serialize the numpy values properly.

```
import jsonpickle
import jsonpickle.ext.numpy as jsonpickle_numpy
jsonpickle_numpy.register_handlers()

with open('file.json', 'wb') as _file:
    _file.write(jsonpickle.encode(pairs).encode())

with open('file.json', 'rb') as _file:
    unpacked = jsonpickle.decode(_file.read())
```